# Z3 check whether two expressions are the same

Tags: z3

While adding constraints in my code, I found I have to add identical constraints into an expression vector for multiple times. Is there any API to detect whether two expressions are exactly the same so that I can remove redundant expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expressions are always internalized to unique pointers. So if you build two expressions using the same sub-expressions, the pointers to them will be the same. You can simply use pointer equality.

Expressions also have so-called "identifiers". The C call to get identifiers is called Z3_ast_get_id, there are corresponding calls in the other APIs for other programming languages
(from C++ you still have to use Z3_ast_get_id, from C# and Java, it is called "Id"/"id").

Comment: one more question, I noticed that the returning type of **Z3_get_ast_id** is unsigned so there are 2^32 ids. Is it possible that two expressions will have the same id as there might be more than 2^32 expressions I guess?