# How to compare two expression in z3?

Tags: z3

I am wondering how to compare two expressions in C++ z3. The following code generates two equal expressions, but the result shows they do not share the same id, which is different from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069496/z3-check-whether-two-expressions-are-the-same). A way to do this is to simplify before checking but the speed is slow due to the simplify overhead. Is there an efficient way to solve it?

```
z3::context c;
z3::expr z1 = c.bool_const("z1");
z3::expr z2 = c.bool_const("z2");
z3::expr z11 = z1 && z2;
z3::expr z22 = z2 && z1;
auto res = Z3_is_eq_ast(c, z11, z22);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: No.

Note that two terms that are semantically identical can still yield `False`, even after a call to `simplify`. The only way to check equivalence for sure is to call `check_sat`.

The way to think about `Z3_is_eq_ast` is that if it says `True`, then you absolutely have the same term. If it says `False`, then it may or may not be the same term, you just don't know. (It's essentially hash-consing, an old idea, and all the caveats apply. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing).